# Image annotate in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, annotate, android-image

Is there any library is available for annotating the image in android.

I would like to know how we can annotate the image which is captured from camera.

Can any one help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just finished working on my image processing app on Android. My app uses library called leadtools and it worked great for me. I didn't use annotations in my app but I saw that they have features for it in their libs. 
You should probably take a look at it and see for yourself.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you provide a link and an example? (Or a link to an example?)